# puzzled by x86 assembly syntax

Tags: assembly, x86

Using CentOS 5.5 in vmware player on a Windows 7 host I wrote an assembly code file gpi.S:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
... /* cut off some code */
lea eax, string_label
mov ebx, [DWORD PTR ds:eax]
push ebx
mov ebx, [DWORD PTR cs:eax]
push ebx
... /* cut off some code */
```

compile:

```
gcc -o gpi gsi.S
```

It's OK.

I later installed a new CentOS version 6.2 in the VMware, then compile the same assembly code with the same command, but I found some errors:

Assembly messages:

```
Error: invalid use of register
```

These errors point to the lines:

```
mov ebx, [DWORD PTR ds:eax]
mov ebx, [DWORD PTR cs:eax]
```

In the CentOS 6.2, the GNU gcc version is 4.6.6. The GNU as version is 2.20.51.0.2 (i686-redhat-lnux).

I think the 2 lines are using the standard Intel assembly syntax, so they are OK in CentOS 5.5. I don't know why.

Comment: The assembly syntax is only relevant for the compiler, not the OS or hardware, so that's not the culprit... Have you tried using the AT&T syntax? Try the table at the end of this section: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s3

Comment: The brackets are weird, dword ptr belongs outside of them.

Comment: I'm rather more surprised that the code used to work in the first place..

Answer (score 1):

as I learned recently,
 `lea ebx, DWORD PTR [ds:eax]` should work. 
If your goal is to just push those pointers via `ebx`, I think you should be able to write `push DWORD PTR [ds:eax]`. I don't know if this will work with the GCC assembler, though.